# take a slice from the end of an nd array in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

There is nd array, e.g., the shape is `[600,800]`. I would like to take a slice of this `2D array`, but I would like to start from upper right corner. This array represents an image with `600*800` pixels. I know I might use `-1` to indicate that I need to start from the right most column. But How to do that with `numpy`?

Comment: Use a sample case to demo the expected outcome? Sounds like a [`basic indexing issue`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative indices in exactly the same manner as in base Python in Numpy. See the [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

An example:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.rand(600, 800)
slice = mat[-200:-1,-200:-1]
print(slice.shape)
```

This will print `(199, 199)`.